# how to access message inbox in android

Tags: java, android, message, inbox

How can I activate my application when a user open the message inbox in android. I can open the inbox from my application . I need a vice verse  where open my app when message is opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never done that, but I suppose you can do a background process that check periodically (not too often though ;) ) the status of unread messages. When the user read the message you show up a notification.

```
final Uri SMS_INBOX = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(SMS_INBOX, null, "read = 0", null, null);
int unreadMessagesCount = c.getCount();
c.deactivate();
```

Comment: i want do like a sms lock app

Comment: Do you mean, prevent the user from accessing his messages (like if he doesn't provide a password)?

Comment: Well, I haven't any idea on how to do this... Sorry I couldn't help you more that that.